# How to take a screenshot on a Windows CE 5.0 device

Tags: screenshot, windows-ce

Does anybody know how I can take a screenshot on a Windows CE 5.0 device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for "ActiveSync Remote Display" -- you may find it bundled with some MS Mobile dev. tools. It lets you display your CE device's screen on your PC which then makes it very easy to grab screen shots using more traditional methods (like Vista Snipper or alt-prtscr).

Comment: Thanks, was a bit of a search to get cerdisp.exe running, but it works!

Comment: Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10601

Answer (score 3):

Try "Screenshot Mobile" (freeware), works on **Windows CE** and Windows Mobile,
more here: http://venea.net/link/screenshot_ce

Comment: Works on a Datalogic FalconX3 Mobile computer with Windows CE 6.0, thx

Answer (score 0):

I've used [My Mobiler](http://www.mymobiler.com/) on 6.0 and 6.1. According to the site it supports 5.0 too, but I can't vouch for that.